# Is it possible to change the datasource of a twb file using tableauserverclient?

Tags: tableau-api

Use Case:
Given a Template.twb that uses Template.hyper I want to create Copy1.hyper and Copy2.hyper that are used in Dashboard1.twb and Dashboard2.twb using automation and the Tableau API.

I've broken this down into three steps, but I can only do the first two currently.

1. Write the hyper files using the Hyper API and publish to Server
   using
2. Create and publish Dashboard1.twb and Dashboard2.twb that still use Template.hyper as a datasource.
3. Change datasource of Dashboard1.twb to Copy1.hyper.

I think this is done using [workbooks.update_connection](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#workbooksupdate_connection), but I haven't gotten it to work or found an example online.

I'm a python novice and mostly using the python scripts made available in the [Hyper API](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/hyper_api/en-us/docs/hyper_api_examples.html) and [Tablea Server Client](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/) to create and publish respectively.

Is this possible?

I can change the datasource by hand in tableau desktop, but we want this automated.
I was thinking I could just append all the data and filter on some unique string generated by each query, but this seems like it would get unwieldy very fast.

Comment: I found a python library that helps me do something similar at https://github.com/bryantbhowell/tableau_tools. This lets you overwrite the hyper files in .twbx files that can then be published. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it seems functionally the same.